# What will be the output of the following SQL Transaction ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

Identify the output for the following Code

```
PRINT 'Before Transaction'
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
BEGIN TRAN T1
PRINT 'After transaction T1 starts'
/* Value of @@TranCount is 1 */
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
BEGIN TRAN T2 save TRAN T2
--save tran T2
PRINT 'After transaction T2 starts'
/* Value of @@TranCount is 2 */
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
ROLLBACK TRAN T2
PRINT 'After transaction T2 roll backs'
/* Value of @@TranCount is still 2 as the rollback failed due to a error */
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT ---------[IT SHOUD BE 1,BUT WHY RESULT IS COMING AS 2?]
ROLLBACK TRAN T1
PRINT 'After transaction T1 roll backs'
/* Value of @@TranCount is 0 */
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
```

What will be the reason for the improper Output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer lies in your code,  as you have used **save TRAN T2**, Transaction T2 get saved and rollback doesn't affect **@@TRANCOUNT** value

Try to run below query multiple times in SQL Server....you will see value of @@TRANCOUNT gets increased by 1, every time you execute this query.

```
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
BEGIN TRAN T2 save TRAN T2
PRINT 'After transaction T2 starts'
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
ROLLBACK TRAN T2
PRINT 'After transaction T2 roll backs'
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
```

Answer (score 0):

From [**MSDN**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx)

> ROLLBACK TRANSACTION decrements @@TRANCOUNT to 0, except for
>   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION       savepoint_name, which does not affect
>   @@TRANCOUNT.

You have transaction **T2** save so `ROLLBACK` has no effect on `@@TRANCOUNT`.

If you use **`ROLLBACK`** on transaction T1 , `@@Trancount` will be reset to **ZERO**